# How to save a IF into a variable PHP

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, save

How can I save this IF into a php variable ?

```
if ($precopromocao > 0 ) 
    echo "<span class='preco_s_promocao'>".$preco."€</span>&nbsp;<span class='preco_c_desconto'>".$precopromocao."€</span>";
        else
    echo $preco."€";
```

I tried:

```
$precofinal = if ($precopromocao > 0 ) 
    echo "<span class='preco_s_promocao'>".$preco."€</span>&nbsp;<span class='preco_c_desconto'>".$precopromocao."€</span>";
        else
    echo $preco."€";
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shorthand](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

```
$var = ($precopromocao > 0 ? echo "<span class='preco_s_promocao'>".$preco."€</span>&nbsp;<span class='preco_c_desconto'>".$precopromocao."€</span>" : echo $preco."€" );
```

### edit

for the ones who hate horizontal scroll:

`$var = ($precopromocao > 0
? echo "<span class='preco_s_promocao'>".$preco."€</span>&nbsp;<span class='preco_c_desconto'>".$precopromocao."€</span>" 
: echo $preco."€" );`

Comment: Oh god please don't spread the message of inline ifs. They just make things more complicated (=harder to read).

Comment: @SamSam Haha, understandable. I was just answering the question. IMO i would use a function for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign your desired output to a variable

```
if ($precopromocao > 0 ) 
{
    $return = "<span class='preco_s_promocao'>".$preco."€</span>&nbsp;<span class='preco_c_desconto'>".$precopromocao."€</span>";
} else {
    $return = $preco."€";        
}
```

Now you can print out the output somewhere else with

```
echo $return;
```